# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when calling print

Tags: python

whenever I run this it will work like 25 to 50% of the time and I can't find out why. Previously I had trouble with if statements but that was an easy fix I forgot about but this just baffles me since it actually works... some of the time. By the way this code was made and run on repl.it.
edit: I added a part at the end that prints the variable rng and it says
typeError:'str' pbject is not callable

```
import random
rng=(random.randint(1,3))
player=input("rock, paper, or scissors ")
if player=="rock":
  if rng==1:
    print("paper covers your rock")
  elif rng==2:
    print=("both rock, tie")
  elif rng==3:
    print("your rock crushes scissors")
  else:
    print("error")
elif player=="paper":
  if rng==1:
    print("both paper, tie")
  elif rng==2:
    print=("your paper covers rock")
  elif rng==3:
    print("scisors cut your paper")
  else:
    print("error")
elif player=="scissors":
  if rng==1:
    print("your scissors cut paper")
  elif rng==2:
    print=("rock crushes your scissors")
  elif rng==3:
    print("both scissors, tie")
  else:
    print("error")
else:
  print("error")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what, exactly, the errors are that you're having? Maybe differentiate your error statements so that you can tell where they're coming from?

Comment: Try replacing `random` with ints until you find the one that fails.

Comment: Green Cloak Guy-that's the problem it doesn't print error it just does nothing half the time

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by it will only work 50% of the time. What is it that is not working? you have to be more clear.

Comment: add another `print` after defining `rng` and give an example run. All your branches are printing something, it will be quite easy to figure it out

Comment: There are several good python debuggers out there that let you step through a program one line at a time. `pdb` likely comes with your distribution. Stepping through a program like this can be very helpful!

Comment: As suggested by tdelaney, if you would change the `random` to fixed numbers, you would find that this always happens for `2` and direct you to the problem more easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
print=("rock crushes your scissors")
```

The `=` is overriding the value of `print`, turning it into a string instead of a function. This causes your print statement not to print!

So, just remove the `=` sign. This typo is actually present in your code three times, as pointed out by @chitown88.

Comment: There are no subsequent prints, it simply doesn't print because of that...

Comment: `print=("your paper covers rock")` and `print=("both rock, tie")` and `print=("rock crushes your scissors")`

Comment: @chitown88 Now that you say it, yes you're right! Answer updated.

Comment: thank you, I copied the section for all the different player outcome, I guess  I missed the typo thank you

Comment: @BrendanClements glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking as answer. Happy coding!